# fortran: debugging emacs with gdb on byobu - unresponsive

Tags: emacs, gdb, byobu

[image: screenshot: byobu,emacs,gdb-mode]

This is my first time using gdb mode on emacs.

As you can see in the minibuffer, `M-n` for `next` doesn't work.

What might be the problem here?

EDIT: this is definitely not due to byobu, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug in Emacs gdb-mode, even without byobu. As a workaround, try typing Ctrl-X Ctrl-A Ctrl-N instead of M-n.

Comment: ok.. i should have tested that out first. I automagically assumed that this had to do something with byobu or screen. *facepalm*